# Autostarting a program on Windows Server 2003 takes 30 seconds

Tags: windows

I installed a Windows Server 2003 virtual machine (KVM, VM specs 1x 3.8GHz and 1.5GB RAM) and I would like it to autostart a .NET framework 3.5 application right after login.

Unfortunately it takes approximately 30 seconds for my application to start up after the desktop is visible. If I start a different application (such as notepad.exe) manually instead it fires up pretty much instantly. Or if I wait 30 seconds and start my application manually it also starts up instantly.

Is there sort of a default delay for autostart applications or is there another factor I probably don't know about? In order to autostart the application I simply put a shortcut into the **All Programs / AutoStart** directory of my start menu.

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks for reading.

**Edit 1:** The CPU usage of my process stays at 0% for the first 30 seconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen similar behavior with XP, and it tends to be applications that require network connections. For some  reason, it can take a while to set up the LAN connection upon bootup.

Is your application using the NIC? If so, i't probably sitting there, waiting for the network to come up.

Comment: Oh lord I didn't notice the NIC was not ready at that moment. All processes using it freeze at boot time until it is up and running. Thanks a lot!

Comment: No problems. If you can figure out what takes it so long to become available, you're good to go.

Comment: Since it's a VM I might just need to change the network driver to a proper one.

Answer (score 1):

Your edit confirms that your process is actually running. So there is no delay for autostart applications: Your application is running. It's just not doing anything for the first 30 seconds.

Debug your application to see why it is not doing anything for 30 seconds.

My psychic powers tell me that your application is communicating with a service that is delay-started. So it has to wait for the service to finish initializing, which takes 30 seconds.

Comment: Many thanks for the quick replies, you guys were right my process was waiting for my NIC all the time.